# ValueError at /category/sugar/ Field 'id' expected a number but got 'sugar'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to make category for eCommerce

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('category/<cats>/', views.categoryView , name = 'category')
]
```

views.py:

```
def categoryView(request, cats):
    products_category = Product.objects.filter(category=cats)
    return render(request, 'store/categories.html', {'cats': cats.title(), 'products_category': products_category})
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category')
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    new = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url
```

html

```
{% for product in products_category %}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
<div class="product-item mb-30">
<a href="#" class="product-img">
<img src="{{ product.imageURL}}" alt="">
<div class="product-absolute-options">
<span class="offer-badge-1">6% off</span>
<span class="like-icon" title="wishlist"></span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

when i try to get category name to my URL got this error, and if i write the category id in URL like this >> http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/3/ I got the correct page, If i clicked on category get this message ValueError at /category/sugar/
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'sugar'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in urls

```
path('category/<str:cats>/', views.categoryView , name='category')
```

in views.py

```
products_category = Product.objects.filter(category__name=cats)
```

here category__name is with double "_"

try it.

Comment: Thank you Zero, you saved me.
It's working perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a string in your url, you need to do the following:

```
path('category/<str:name>/', views.categoryView , name = 'category')
```

Refer to the Django documentation: 
 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: When i put str i got the right URL with this error Field 'id' expected a number but got 'sugar'.

Comment: I don't understand where `cats.title` is coming from, because I don't see `title` anywhere in your code. I think that's where your error may be.

Comment: I removed it and same problem here ( cats.title() make the first letter caps